# PHP open and read xz file

Tags: php

For a plain text file I'm using:

```
$fh = fopen("log.txt", 'r') or die($php_errormsg);
while (!feof($fh)) {
   $line = fgets( $fh, 4096 );
   echo $line;
}
```

Is there a similar way to do this with a .xz file ?
I've googled and I'm not finding much related to it.

Basically I need to be able to read through a .xz compressed file in the same way I do with a text file.

Thanks

Comment: If it is a compressed file then you can think it like encoded file and before decoding this you can't read, until it is in-build feature. So first search to decompress this `.xz` file then try to read.

Comment: Either build a non-standard module https://github.com/payden/php-xz, or pipe-read the file via [`popen`](http://php.net/popen) and `xz -dc …`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the .xz file with `popen()`.

```
$fname = 'log.xz';
$fh = popen("xz -cd --files0=" . $fname, 'r');
```